# Can I effectively use both React's useCallback and nested function hoisting?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can I hoist a nested, event-handling function without a performance hit? Basically, I wanna do something like this:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const handleCallback = useCallback(handleChange, [props.onChange]);
  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={props.value} />;

  function handleChange(event) {
    props.onChange(event.currentTarget.value);
  }
};
```

Yes, I could move this outside the `Component` function, but with more complex functions, that becomes a pain in the ass.

Comment: I do think the example is valid, and it's no different in term of performance than if you would had inline the callback in `useCallback` itself.  The question is more: why would you do that to begin with? Just inline it. BTW, in your specific example, I would argue that `useCallback` is redundant, and could be removed

Comment: Reads more cleanly to me, especially in more complicated examples

Comment: Legit question: you don't think a controlled input would be a good candidate for memoization? Wouldn't `props.value` constantly changing trigger a lot of renders? Or maybe I'm not quite grasping that

Comment: I can direct you to https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578 for a generic answer to that topic

Comment: Sufficient to say that in your case, keeping the identity of handleCallback stable doesn't buy anything, even the opposite, since react needs to compare your function with the old one. If props.onChange is not stable, you still create handleChange every time, but you add a useless diff operation on top of that. And if that's not the case, you still hurt readability of code. The `input` element is not pure anyway, it will re-render nonetheless, even providing the same function to it.

Comment: Can you think of a simple change to my component that would justify useCallback? I'm struggling to find a good use based on feedback I've received, from you and elsewhere.

Thanks for the help by the way :)

Comment: Any time you require to provide a stable identity of a function for whatever reason. Could be because a pure component require one to work properly, could be because a dependency argument from a `useEffect` require the function not to change. Sometimes you just need a function to remain the same, not matter what. I think this could help you: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: just to clarify, according to your question, what can you move outside the Component function ?